# Powerpoint hyperlink limit at 255 characters

Tags: hyperlink, powerpoint

I (have to) use PowerPoint 2007 under Windows. I want to create a hyperlink with several GET-Parameters, thus it is quite long. It seems that PowerPoint cuts the hyperlink in the "add hyperlink form" to 255 characters. I wonder since Microsoft says the limit is at 900 or 1032 characters at

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4e668216-3341-4784-a8d4-2c7023334ac2/hyperlink-limit-in-powerpoint-2007?forum=officegeneral.

Do you have an idea how to use a hyperlink with at least 300-400 characters?
I cannot shrink the hyperlink due to the information that has to be passed the linked website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft may have read the feedback and at least in recent Powerpoint ("1803" from Office 365) the hyperlinks can have a length of 500 characters (and maybe more).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a limitation on the text field where you actually input the URL.

You could install OpenOffice which may allow you to edit the URL with full length. From there, you can save as PPT. That would certainly confirm if it is a PPT limitation, or a input box text field limitation (which I suspect).